# My Bluemix IoT Foundation organization is not shown on webpage

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I have a Bluemix account with organization defined, but when I login to IoTF via the webpage https://internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/ my organization is not shown.  I see a message that says "You are not a member of any organization".

I am unable to add any devices as a result.  What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely explanation is that you were a temporary member of your IoTF organization and that has subsequently expired.

When you create an IoTF service using Bluemix, an IoTF organization is created and your IBM ID is added as a temporary member.  This temporary membership expires after 24 hours and the effect is similar to what you are describing.

If you were to access IoTF using the service tile in Bluemix (Launch Dashboard) then you would be logged straight in to your organization.  At this point you will be able to add members (including yourself) to the IoTF organization and then be able to log in directly at https://internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/

The reason for this is that if a Bluemix user created an IoTF service, there is not necessarily the affirmation that that user will forever be authorized to access it.  By making that user a temporary member, it is able to log in directly for 24 hours only until the ID is added as a permanent member, or that user always accesses the IoTF dashboard using the Bluemix service tile.  The intention is that without positive action the user creating the service will still need access in Bluemix, in order to access IoTF.